# Ubuntu: how to create a user with ----disabled-password and still have them sudo (which fails as there is no password)

Tags: bash, linode

I am trying to write a linode stackscript, which is a bash file which is run as root when you build a new image. It can prompt for parameters such as USER, KEY and possibly, but not ideally, PASSWORD.

In the script I create a user "bob", then

```
adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" --shell /bin/bash $USER
adduser $USER sudo
```

We are creating the user with certificate and with no password, the user, once logged in via SSH, cant sudo as it prompts for a password that doesnt exist.

I assume there are 2 options here:

1. give it a password. Unfortunately, there is no option to do this via parameter, so is there a way to do it without prompts (not interactive)?
2. fix it so bob doesn't need to enter a password.

Answer (score 3):

Instead disabling password, create a user without password.

workaround

`adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" --shell /bin/bash $USER
 usermod -g sudo $USER
 passwd -d $USER`

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution, using option 1.  I had not heard of chpasswd, but it seems to work with the unattended script. Now the user has a password for sudo.

adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" --shell /bin/bash $USER
adduser $USER sudo
echo "$USER:$PASS" | sudo chpasswd